# Mysql comma serparated string to columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called lang which contains a comma separated string en,zh-hans,uk

| id | lang |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | en,zh-hans,uk |
| 2 | en,zh |

how do i loop this comma-separated string so i can have this result

| en | zh-hans | uk |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Use double SUBSTRING_INDEX by a comma - first with N=1,2,..., second with N=-1. Check the amount of commas for to avoid multiple copies of last value.

Comment: Use the php [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function on the result retrieved to form an array. Recommend avoiding storing multiple values in a single database columns.